# Parallel Process is not updating WPF Collection List

Tags: parallel-processing, task

In my WPF application, I have a Data Grid which populates with a ObservableCollection collection. Suppose I have such 10 student data in the grid. Each student is capable of doing 2 long running works or process and updates the status of the process back to the grid. I want to do those 2 process simultaneously. So I used Task and Parallel.Invoke methods. The work flow is as follows.

1. I populated the Student data collection in the Grid.
2. I clicked on a start button.
3. In the click event of the start button, i did the following code.

   ```
      foreach (Student stud in StudentLists)
       {
           stud.Status = "started..";
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartProcess(stud));
       }
   ```
4. In the StartProcess,

   ```
   Parallel.Invoke(() =>
       {                
           MarkService ms = new MarkService(stud_data); 
           Student s = ms.GetMarkProcess(); // This will return the stud_data in the above line

           Student studitem = StudentLists.Where(x => x.RollID == s.RollID).FirstOrDefault(); // find the student in the grid
           if (studitem != null)
           {                    
               studitem.Status = "Mark Got it";  // if find, updating the status
           }
       },                              

       () =>
       {
           SentMarks(poll); // this is another method to be executed parallel
       } 
       );
   ```

When executing all the 10 students process, each student in the grid became the same data.
Or only 2 or 1 student in the Grid is showing Status "Mark Got it". Other rows show "started.." status only.

Why this is not updating the collection.

I have used INotofyPropertyChanged and raisng the event when property updated.
In the XAML, each binding is used in Two way mode.

There is no error. But the 1 or 2 items in the student collection is updating some times. Sometimes the collection contains the last students data for all the 9 items.

It is not updating the exact student object in the Grid. what is wrong in my code ?

Any help in this case ???

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your referencing a UI control from another thread. You should create an in memory data structure that a grid can use as DataSource (anything that implements IEnumerable). I would suggest using the ConcurrentBag data structure for parallelized code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx). Once you've updated each of the student records in the ConcurrentBag you set the grid's datasource to that bag.